# How to .append() new message on websocket to page with CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, websocket

I'm having problems conceptualizing how to `.append()` a new message received on the WebSocket to the client-side chat box with CSS styles.

Right now, I have a `forloop` that populates the chat box when there are objects in the `ChatMessage` model.

```
{% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
```

This obviously populates the page with `sent_msg` and `incoming_msg` only when the page is refreshed, which means that any messages received over the WebSocket (and then saved to the db) won't appear until the user refreshes the page.

I am new to a lot of client-side JS / Jquery stuff so forgive me, but I want to use `.append()` to echo the message in the chatbox as soon as it is sent/received over the WebSocket, leading to a real-time chat feel.

I've tried appending the message inside the `forloop` but it obviously appends to every message sent or received thus far and does not have CSS styles applied to it (the `what` is the appended text).

[image: example]

If I append it outside of the forloop, it doesn't have any of the styles applied (placement etc) and appends underneath the first message sent (I know I can do `prepend` but that still doesn't really fix the problem)

thread.html

```
 {% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
    {% if chat.user == user %}
    <div class="outgoing_msg">
      <div class="outgoing_msg_img"> <img src="{{ chat.user.profile.image.url }}"></div>
      <div class="sent_msg" id="sent_msg">
        <p>{{ chat.message }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="incoming_msg">
      <div class="incoming_msg_img"><img src="{{ chat.user.profile.image.url }}"></div>
      <div class="received_msg" id="received_msg">
          <p>{{ chat.message }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

base.html

```
var loc = window.location
    var incomingMsg = $('#incoming_msg')
    var sentMsg = $('#sent_msg')

    // below is the message I am receiving
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("message", e)
      var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
      incomingMsg.append('<li>' + chatDataMsg.message + ' from ' + chatDataMsg.username + '</li>')
    }

    // below is the message I am sending
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("open", e)
      formData.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var msgText = msgInput.val()
        sentMsg.append('<li>' + msgText + '</li>')
```

Comment: first, `var incomingMsg = $('#incoming_msg')` is undefined since you don't have a div with that id. Second, in your template, you're creating multiple divs with the same id (`sent_msg` and `received_msg`) because they are in a for-loop. That's not allowed, and id has to be unique in the entire HTML document. Try adding a unique identifier (e.g. `{{chat.id}}`) that will change through every loop. Finally, in your socket.onmessage, just append it to the correct, unique div by select the one where the message belongs to. Somehow you need to figure out the chat belonging to the `chatDataMsg`.

Comment: When you receive a message, you need to construct the same HTML structure you have in your django template: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8gvd12fx/

Comment: @dirkgroten Hi Dirk, thanks for your comment. I keep forgetting about the id problem in a forloop so for now, have just taken out the IDs and left div classes. I can do what I want without IDs right? I have tried appending it to the unique div but the problem is that it does not show up because the instance of the new message in the forloop doesn't appear until the page is refreshed. Bear brown added an answer that I think I understand...creating sort of a temporary template that does not show up on the page until the `.append` is called then it appears until the page is refreshed.

Comment: @ChrisG Hi Chris, thank you for making a jsfiddle! I am looking through it now. I understand what you mean about making another separate structure just to echo the messages, but one problem is that it stays on the screen for me? Bearbrown commented below an example of how to make it only appear when it is `.appended` to. Although in your Jsfiddle they only appear when submit is pressed, which is what I want. I also get an error when trying to implement `$chat is not defined`

Comment: EDIT: I wrote the chat variable incorrectly, will get back to you in a moment!

Comment: Hi Trilla, the fiddle is primarily there to underline that you need to replicate the existing HTML for additional messages instead of simply appending a `<li>`. Not sure what you mean by "stays on the screen"? You mean when you refresh the page, you want to see all past messages again? That's a whole other box of worms and depends on your server side implementation. And it's definitely out of the scope of this SO question.

Comment: @ChrisG My apologies, I don't mean stays on the screen in that way, I already have that handled server side. One of my questions is in the jsfiddle, it starts with the existing empty chat templates on the screen. I guess I am saying that they need to be hidden, and only appear when appended to, otherwise client-side it looks confusing as there are 2 permanent blank messages (one sent and one received) on screen?

Comment: I see, those were just example messages. Again, the point of the fiddle isn't to provide you with code you can simply copy and paste, it's supposed to demonstrate how to compose and insert HTML elements more complex than `<li>message</li>`. Still, I've updated the fiddle. But so far it doesn't even distinguish between own and other people's messages.

Comment: @ChrisG So to clarify, we are using `append` to actually consecutively add on classes to the message echo until it resembles the structure of the previous messages? And that's why in the updated fiddle, you were able to take out all of the HTML code and just leave `div class=chat`?

Comment: What my code does is 1. grab the main `<div id='chat'>` using `$('#chat')` 2. create three nested divs, an img and a p to compose the elements of a single message 3. call `.append()` on the div from step 1 to insert the message at its end - - - yes, I'm also adding classes to the various elements a single message consists of (by calling `.addClass()`), but that's because you had those classes in your server-template. Here's a simplified version without any classes: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p8jd1ng3/

Comment: I guess part of the confusion is that you're referring to (HTML) elements using the word "class". A class is a group, and any element can become part of this group. Classes are mainly used to apply CSS styles to a bunch of different elements, instead of just one.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I was referring to elements with the word classes, thanks for the correction. Okay I've seen the new jsfiddle, thank you for posting that! Also one more question. What is the reasoning behind using `var $chat = $('#chat')` as opposed to `var chat = $('#chat')`

Comment: It's just a reminder that `$chat` is a jQuery object. Without jQuery I'd use `var chat = document.getElementById('chat');`.

Comment: @ChrisG How would you distinguish the two messages sent through the websocket, sent and received? As they are both getting created with the same elements (3 nested divs, img, p), there is no differentiation between them (regarding styling)?

Comment: One way is to compare the message author to the logged in User; if they're the same, add a different class, and use that to style the message differently. I've updated the original fiddle accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8gvd12fx/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much, that fiddle really helped me wrap my mind around the logic. I tried writing an if else statement but it didn't work so ended up following a similar structure to yours! It works perfectly now.

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

based on the comment, you should use the class selector for the incoming block, and i think the good solution is to use the template.

some where in your `thread.html`

```
<span class="imcoming-tpl" style="display:none;">
  <div class="incoming_msg_img">
      <img src="src" class="chat-img-src">
  </div>
  <div class="received_msg" id="received_msg">
      <p class="chat-message">text</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

and in the js part

```
var incomingMsg = $('.incoming_msg')
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("message", e)
  var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
    var tpl = $('.imcoming-tpl').clone();
    tpl.removeClass('imcoming-tpl');
    tpl.find('.chat-message').html(chatDataMsg.message);
    // Some code to add img src need to add the user.profile.image.url on the back side
    // tpl.find('.chat-img-src').attr(src, chatDataMsg.url);
    incomingMsg.append(tpl);
    tpl.show()
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. It makes the most sense so far because we need the template to only appear when `.appended()` to otherwise there will be a permanent blank HTML message on screen all the time which isn't right. I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefine`

Comment: I didn't realize you can solve the blank message problem by just removing that HTML code and then keeping the JS code where it creates the classes using `append`. Have you seen the JS fiddle above? I've managed to get it working using that. So it seems possible without a template tag, what do you think?

Comment: hi i updated the answer, not sure the good code but i hope it should work. And here the single snippet as example https://gist.github.com/gitavk/4f83a60d3f938b7b7c7af21f6308ac16

Comment: Okay I will try it. Right now I am using https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8gvd12fx/ and it works